# Add comment/url to VCALENDAR

Tags: icalendar

I am looking for a way to specify a URL or comment in a icalendar file which will be shown by user agents in some sort of details or properties window.
(Emphasis on being shown by user agents)

I don't want to specify this for a single event but rather a whole `VCALENDAR` element.
It should work with all common user agents.

I'd like to use this to include a feedback URL/email address, that users can discover without having to inspect the raw file.
(The ical files are the only communication channel I have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to using `X-WR-CALDESC` (and `X-WR-CALNAME`) to specify my description (and human readable name).

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably noticed, the VCALENDAR component has very few properties defined on it (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.7).

There is a new IETF draft that extends this list. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daboo-icalendar-extensions
Amongst those, a URL property is defined at the VCALENDAR level but it is defined as pointing to the source of the iCalendar stream, rather than to an explainatory URL.
On the other hand, you could probably stuff both feedback URL and email address in the newly defined DESCRIPTION property (or ping back the author if you feel that a feedback url property should be added to the draft).

As far as user agents making use of those properties, this is another story of course. Which user agents are we talking about ?

Comment: User agents include google calendar, recent versions of android (over google calendar), the osx calendar, recent versions of iOS, thunderbird/lightning and outlook.
This is the reason I want to use this URL, to give users a way to report errors.

Answer (score -1):

Some notes on my experiences with different calendar clients that may help others.

iOS iCalendar app seems to recognize URLs in the Description field of a vCalendar item, and turns them into tappable hyperlinks. MS Outlook also recognizes these.
e.g.

```
DESCRIPTION:Go here: http://stackoverflow.com \n
```

Some clients support the vcalendar URL property e.g

```
URL:http://stackoverflow.com
```

In iOS iCalendar app these display clearly in a URL field.

You may also have some luck with a anchor tag embedded in an html doc in the X-ALT-DESC e.g.

```
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML><BODY><A HREF="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflo
    w.com</A></BODY>\n</HTML>
```

Clearly, you need to test URL's in vcalendar appointments on all clients you need to support.

There's probably other ways to add URL's too.